# Xcode - Simulating an update of data in applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: xcode, debugging, testing, dynamic

I'm doing a check for updated data from the web in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` but how would I test this in the simulator? I have no control of when the updates from the web are made so I need to trigger an update myself within Xcode when it's already running in the simulator.

I need to some dynamic testing so to speak.

Comment: you should be able to hit the home button on the simulator and then click into your app and trigger it (the Xcode session should still be going), this does cause some weird weird problems eventually.. if you do it then quit the Xcode run and etc..but thats just the simulator breaking.

Comment: But how do I trigger the update manually? It's just basically a matter of populating some vars with data that would simulate an update but I don't know how to do this when the application is already running in the simulator? One way is to turn it off and change the variable and then run it again but that way is quite tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not suer by what you mean by 'check for updated data from the web' though sounds like you are getting refreshed Data from a WebData source. Can you Simulate that Web Data source?  There are many WebServers you can install that you can create a Quick page to send you back Data when you query it.   We do this with our App. Ultimately we will be querying our Ultimate Web Data, but while testing we simulate the data on the web with our own web server. A few pages in the background and you can have it return you the data that you need. We use XML of the communications back and forth.

Then once we go live, we switch the web server name and we are good to go.

Comment: I used a DropBox service for this, very handy. Thanks for your advice.